# Using vars() for variable names from imported modules?

Tags: python, variables, import, module

I am trying to do something like

```
import module_name
something = vars()["module_name.var_name"]
```

On program execution, I get

```
KeyError: 'module_name.var_name'
```

i.e. It doesn't work. Any way I can make it work?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars

Comment: Try `vars(module_name)`

Comment: @match that worked, thanks! :) Now how to mark you your answer as the solution...

Comment: turned it into an answer

Comment: I still don't really get what you are trying to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vars()` with no argument works 'locally'. If you want to look at variables in another module, you need to pass that module as the argument:

```
vars(module_name)
```

You can then find a specific variable using `[]`

```
vars(module_name)['var_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

This might solve it:

```py
dir(vars()['module_name'])['var_name']
```

If not, I suggest you to explain about what you're trying to do and not about this specific problem